# Is there a way to target an interface without knowing its name or mac address?

Tags: ovh, netplan

We're running a handful of virtual servers at OVH, which use openstack.

Most of the servers have a public interface as well as a private interface which is connected to a "virtual private cloud", or vRack as OVH terms it.

I've seen a few times that a server goes away, and then comes back up with the private interface having a new name (e.g. `ens6` instead of `ens4`) as well as a new mac address.

This breaks the netplan configuration, which usually looks like a variation of this :

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens6:
            addresses: [192.168.100.71/24]
            dhcp4: false
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:bc:73:48
```

Is there a way to target an interface without knowing its name or mac address?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Did you report the problem to OVH?

Comment: s means PCI slot, so the (virtual) hardware changed. Complain to the hosting provider that you want predicable hardware.

Comment: OK, so based on the feedback here this should not be expected from OVH in any case. I'll report this back to OVH if / when it happens again.